# Extracting faq sub-intent from a custom action

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am using the following configuration: Rasa Version : 2.2.9 Rasa SDK Version : 2.2.0 Rasa X Version : None Python Version : 3.7.6 Operating System : Linux-5.4.0-71-generic-x86_64-with-debian-bullseye-sid

I would like to get a faq or chitchat sub-intent (not intent) form a custom action. When I use this command :

tracker.latest_message['intent'].get('name')

I get the intent faq… I would like to get a sub-intent like faq/ask_weather or faq/ask_name instead or even ask_weather or ask name.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this in our demo [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-demo/blob/main/actions/actions.py#L180-L184):

```
full_intent = (
            tracker.latest_message.get("response_selector", {})
            .get("faq", {})
            .get("full_retrieval_intent")
        )
```

If you're looking for the full intent of a "chitchat" retrieval intent, you'll have to replace "faq" in the above with "chitchat", and so on, for whatever prefix.